# Kivy to print changing variables

Tags: python, variables, kivy

There's a project I am working on and I am using kivy.
I receive some input and that input gets stored in a variable that changes almost every 50 milliseconds
I just want kivy to print JUST the current value of the variable in the text box.
I know this is not a good representation of the question. But I just tried to simplify it.

If you didn't understand the question very well, the next section is a bit more detailed:

I am using an arduino to get some input.
That input is stored into a variable `myData`. So obviously it keeps changing.
I want myData to be printed in the kivy screen. You don't really need knowledge of arduino for this question.
Heres the python code for arduino:

```
import serial
import time



info = serial.Serial('com3',9600)

def arduino():
        while True:
                if info.inWaiting()>0 :
                        myData = info.readline()
                        myData = myData.decode('utf-8')
                        
        

arduino()
```

Python code for kivy is pretty standard. The kivy file is what I need.

Comment: So what's the problem that you can't solve? Can you post your kivy code showing the point where you get stuck?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not coding service. You should show that you have attempted something and faced and issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a label, schedule a Clock update, and return it...

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock

import serial
import time

myData = ""
info = serial.Serial('com3',9600)


def arduino():
    global myData
    while True:
        if info.inWaiting() > 0 :
            myData = info.readline()
            myData = myData.decode('utf-8')

arduino()

class MyLabel(Label):
    
    def update_text(self, dt):
        global myData
        self.text = myData    # Update text

    def on_kv_post(self, instance):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, 1/60)    # Scheduling


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        label = MyLabel()
        return label


MyApp().run()
```